# Gvim middle mouse click horizontal scroll

Tags: vim, mouse, gvim, scrolling

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with Gvim 7.4

Using my external mouse, I was wondering how to achieve 'horizontal scroll', I read all the documentation about it but still haven't figured out how to achieve it. 'horizontal scroll' to me means holding down the middle mouse button and moving the mouse horizontally. But that's just not working. Essentially what I want to achieve is something like this [VS plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7b2f069f-01f8-4a6a-bd46-b5b1194911e9).

I know about `zl/zh` but I want to scroll horizontally from the mouse (by holding MMB and moving horizontally like I said, somehow, maybe?)

So when does `ScrollWheelLeft`/`ScrollWheelRight` events get fired?

Thanks!

Comment: Complex concerns with mouse when using Vim could be an indication that you should consider changing to another application. [From Vim FAQ, 1.1. What is Vim?](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-1.1): `Vim is a text editor which includes almost all the commands from the Unix program "Vi" and a lot of new ones. All commands can be given with the keyboard. This has the advantage that you can keep your fingers on the keyboard and your eyes on the screen.`

Comment: @mMontu: I completely understand that. I've been using vim (VsVim) in my professional C# development for over 2 years now. I'm completely addicted to my setup with VS/VSVim and R#. But recently I decided to try my best and move my development from VS to just Gvim with the help of OmniSharp etc (of course I still use VS for debugging and things that vim can't do and R# for heavy-duty refactoring - it's just that major coding and basic refactoring is done in vim). IMO horizontal scrolling is very helpful when browsing the code in Visual studio, it's just very natural, so that's why.

Comment: Plus vim is meant to be bent however the developer wants, it doesn't force a specific workflow on you. But ofc I get what you're saying. I use mouse scrolling when I'm just reading, not writing. So it doesn't hurt/ slow me down or get me off of the home row when typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better approach is to use `Ctrl-F/Ctrl-D/Ctrl-B/Ctrl-U` or any of the number of alternatives on the keyboard.

Having said that, you could try the mapping the middle mouse button to existing functionality on other mouse buttons:

```
map <MiddleDrag> <LeftMouse>
```

Additional information:

[Vim tip "Mighty Mouse"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Mouse)

[Vim tip 696: "Make mouse drag not select text or go into visual mode"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_mouse_drag_not_select_text_or_go_into_visual_mode)

---

Edit:

The mapping above works well here.

If you need additional/finer control you may check for additional information on [:help 'mouse'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27mouse%27) -- it contains links to other relevant help entries.

In order to handle the events directly (and possibly pass to vim-smooth-scroll plugin) you should map the keycodes generated by the mouse. This is explained for *nix in [:help MouseDown](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#%3CMouseDown%3E).

Comment: Thanks. We're making progress. I didn't know about `MiddleDrag` I had some crazy ideas of hooking up WinAPI and calculating mouse coordinates and deltas to get the right amount of offset. The problem with vim's page up/down etc is that they're not smooth, they scroll instantly. There's a plugin I came across recently https://github.com/terryma/vim-smooth-scroll didn't give it much attention. I'll give it another look. Maybe I could wire a solution with MiddleDrag somehow.

Comment: Do you know of any function in Vim's API to get the mouse position? (not cursor/caret position)

Answer (score 0):

This I found to be very helpful as well

```
    "Scroll screen one char in all directions 'without' moving cursor
    nnoremap <C-i> <C-y>
    nnoremap <C-k> <C-e>
    vnoremap <C-i> <C-y>
    vnoremap <C-k> <C-e>
    nnoremap <C-j> zh
    nnoremap <C-l> zl
    vnoremap <C-j> zh
    vnoremap <C-l> zl
```